# Adding line marks to an existing plot

Tags: r

I am trying to add line markings on a barplot, but I do not know how.

This is what I want to achieve (lines added with paint):
[image]

So far I've managed to only draw the plot, but I have no idea how to add the lines. Here's my code:

```
columnNames = names(myExcerpt)

for(i in length(myExcerpt)) 
{
   barplot(t(as.matrix(myExcerpt[i])), main=columnNames[i], xpd=F,
        ylim = range(pretty(c(min(myExcerpt[[i]]), myExcerpt[[i]]))))
}
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: use lines() or abline() perhaps?

Comment: For your case, maybe: `abline(h=900,col="red");
abline(h=1000,col="green"); abline(h=1100,col="blue");`
use the commands after barplot.

Comment: @ReubenL. Ok, that works for the drawing part, but still the description eludes me

Comment: by descritpion, do you mean adding the `?legend` ... `abline(h=c(900, 1000, 1100), col=c("red", "green", "blue")) ;
legend("topright", legend=paste("label", 1:3), lwd=2, col=c("red", "green", "blue"))`

Comment: Yes, I do. Thanks, those really help. Would you post them as answers?

Comment: please feel free to post it  Mario